# Getting things right regarding typo questions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Question in question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091198/using-and-in-a-php-if-statement

Quite clearly a typo, so I close-voted as such, downvoted for lack of effort (any basic code editor "should" have bracket-matching to tell you about this kind of error) and commented to point out the typo (to save everyone's time, especially OP's).

Then a bunch of near-identical answers popped up on the question. So I went through and downvoted each one, commenting the same with each one to explain that typo questions are off-topic and should be closed (or ignored if you don't have enough rep)

I'm getting backlash for this, and there seem to be an almost alarming number of upvotes instead.

As someone who used to jump to answer these questions, I want to learn how to do better, so... am I heading in the right direction here, or have I overstepped?

Comment: No. What you did is perfectly fine.

Comment: No, it isn't. The consensus is not clear about what to do with such answers in the first place, and downvoting them *en masse* is choosing a side and may end up crossing the line. There has to be another way.

Comment: Close and delete the question. No question, no problem. :P

Comment: @Mysticial, bah, you and your simple solutions to complex problems ;p

Comment: -1'd all of them too.

Comment: Many syntax error answers deserve a downvote when they amount to little more than "here's your fixed code" dumps. Seldomly do you see the actual language tutoring the newcomer OP or following users would benefit from. Though I'd reserve downvotes for those that really ought to know better (>2K answerers).

Comment: @mario I considered posting an answer that included information on how to detect problems like that in future, but I wasn't sure if that'd be right.

Comment: I don't think this question is marked correctly as a duplicate. The referenced question discussed poor-quality questions in general, whereas this question is specific to typos, which are a little bit different.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not a huge fan of downvoting answers based on the *question*, although sometimes they certainly beg for it.

But regardless, commenting on each answer with a critique of the question is noise at best and probably asking for trouble. I see a moderator has already removed your comments; that seems wise.

Here as elsewhere, if you're gonna bother commenting then *make your comment about the post you're commenting on.* If you've nothing to say about the answers themselves, then why comment?

As [Mysticial noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258706/getting-things-right-regarding-typo-questions#comment37609_258706), you can go back in a couple days and delete the question, which takes care of the answers as well. No muss, no fuss...

Answer (score 4):

What you did is absolutely fine.

Typo-based questions are clearly off-topic. Most answerers on this question seem to be experienced ones with several hundred rep, there is even a 10K. That means they are most probably aware of what they are doing.

Also, the downvote arrow says "This answer is not useful":

- The answers **seem** to be useful to the OP, they solve the immediate problem. But the OP still does not know how to find basic mistakes in his code. He is still unable to debug and now he is less inclined to learn it. We can say **these answers even harm the OP**. In fact he only learnt that he can post his basic debugging problems on Stack Overflow instead of solving them himself.
- **The answers are clearly not useful for future visitors**, the whole thing is about a simple typo. People will not find the question and even if they do, they are in no better situation than the poor OP.
- The answers do not add any value to Stack Overflow. **They are not useful for the site**.

That means downvoting seems to be the right action to take, besides closing the question. If you think it could help, you can leave a comment, but get ready for angry mobs. Never get between a repwhore and his prey :).

*As someone who used to jump to answer these questions.*

Answer (score 3):

I think downvoting answers to bad questions isn't the way to go, especially with typo questions. Typo questions are usually unsalvageable and will likely be deleted; this means all you need to do is add a close vote and that should take care of everything.

Go put that [PHP dupe hammer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xOy3.png) to work as well! If a typo question is actually useful at this stage of StackOverflow it probably already exists.

Comment: Okay. What about the commenting part? Should I still leave a comment on answers? Or should I comment on the question and hope the answerers see it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.  You can vote however you want, but please don't downvote an answer because you think that no one should answer the question.  **Voting on answers should be based on their merit, period.**  If the question is a typo question, then you can vote to close it.

Comment: Downvoting these answers is based on their merit.

Comment: Merit has aspects other than the merely technical. An answer which merely points out a typo has little merit. It contributes nothing to building SO as a knowledge base, and complicates the deletion process.