# What happens to reputation points of an answer when the question is deleted?

Tags: support, questions, reputation, deleted-questions

<sub>I am sure that this has been asked before but I cannot find it in 'Questions that may already have your answer'.</sub>

I asked a question. I got a correct answer. Turns out that I had a typo in my code.

I would like to delete this question (by flagging it, as it has an answer) because it will probably not help the world but still would like to acknowledge the time took by the answerer (by accepting and upvoting). What happens to his rep points if the question is deleted?

Comment: I think this has been answered here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66746/how-does-a-deleted-question-affect-reputation-and-badge-evaluation

Comment: If the answer is on the site for >= 60 days, and has a net score >= 3 then the reputation remains. Otherwise, it is lost. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262593/do-i-lose-reputation-if-i-delete-my-own-question-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas: somehow. It talks about the rep someone engaged (by downvoting). I am interested in the rep awarded to someone else than me (which I would him to keep)

Comment: Very related [Getting things right regarding typo questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258706/getting-things-right-regarding-typo-questions).  The consensus is that people will want to delete your question when it becomes eligible for deletion after closure.  And yes, the answerer's reputation change will be reversed.